# Form is not available and doesn't update while a loop is in progress

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have a method that has a for loop in it.  In the for loop I want to update some label's text on the mainform, but the changes are only done after the loop ends.

I tried to do it on another thread like this:

```
Thread firstthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myMethod));
firstthread.Start();
```

When I did that I got an `InvalidOperationException` because of trying to access controls on another thread or something like that.

How should I update the labels(or other controls) on the mainform from a loop while the loop is in progress?

Comment: This is an olsd favourite, here is one reference... http://osherove.com/blog/2006/3/1/the-3-ways-to-create-a-thread-safe-gui-with-net-20-with-one.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `BackgroundWorker`.  Place your long running loop inside of the `DoWork` event handler; it will run in a background thread and not block the UI thread.  You can set `ReportProgress` to true and then attach an event handler to that to allow you to update a label (or whatever else) periodically.  The ProgressReported event runs in the UI thread.  You can also add a handler to the Completed event which runs in the UI thread as well.

You can look at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for BackgroundWorker for details and code samples.

Comment: Soon I'm going to deal with that solution, but it's not that simple.

Comment: Well, usually it really is that simple.  If it's not, then you'll need to provide more details about what complicates your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the Invoke and BeginInvoke methods on the Form (for Windows.Forms) or on the Dispatcher object of the window (for WPF).

For example:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Text = "ciao"));
```

changes the title bar of the form.

BeginInvoke is asynchronous - it doesn't wait for the change to happen - while Invoke is synchronous and blocks until the change is done. Unless you have specifically that need, I would suggest using BeginInvoke which reduces the chances of an accidental deadlock.

This will allow you to update UI from a concurrent thread - and works whatever threading mechanism you are using (TPL tasks, plain Thread, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As Servy said, you can use something like in this simple example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (string)e.UserState;
        SetValue(text);//or do whatever you want with the received data
    }
    void SetValue(string text)
    {
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            string text = "Value is " + i.ToString();
            bgw.ReportProgress(1, text);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm calling ReportProgress method many times in a for loop but it just do it once

Comment: I didn't tried your code, just something like that I found [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) before you answered and now it works but I think the problem is the way I want to update, but that's tomorrow problem, I think I'll sleep on it.